# Yet another person asking how to center a navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I have tried probably 15 suggestions from stackoverflow on how to center nav. Can you help? I just want to center the nav and be able to hover over Expertise without the rest of the nav bar getting jumbled around.

Here is my markup:

```
<nav id="header-home-nav">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li id="" class=""><a href="" onclick="doCircleExit(this)">About</a></li> 
            <li id="line-li"><p class="nav-lines">|</p></li> 
            <li id="" class=""><a href="" onclick="doCircleExit(this)">Contact</a></li> 
            <li id="" class=""><p class="nav-lines">|</p></li> 
            <li id="" class=""><a href="">Expertise</a>
                <ul id="" class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="">&#9654; Finance</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">&#9654; Operations</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">&#9654; Capital Management</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">&#9654; Capital Management</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">&#9654; Capital Management</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">&#9654; Capital Management</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">&#9654; Capital Management</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">&#9654; Capital Management</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

css:

```
#menu {
position: relative;
font-size: 0.8em;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;   
overflow: visible;
z-index: 2;
height: 35px; 
width:100%;    
}

#menu ul {
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
z-index: 3;
width:100%;
background-color: #666666;
}

 #menu li {
background-color: #1b1b1b;
display: block;
float: left;

position:relative;
}

#menu a {
color: #ffffff;
display: block;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;

margin: 0;
padding: 10px 20px;
}

#menu a:hover {
color: #000000;
margin: 5px 10px;
padding: 5px 10px;
background-color: #C0C0C0;
border-radius: 10px;
}

#menu ul.sub-menu {
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 100%;
z-index:100;

}

#menu ul.sub-menu li {
width: 200px;
background-color: #C0C0C0;
border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #666666;
z-index:5;

}

#menu ul.sub-menu li a {
color: #000;
text-align: center;
margin: 5px 10px;
padding: 5px 10px;
text-align: left;
}

#menu ul.sub-menu li a:hover {
color: snow;
background-color: #666666;
}

#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
display: block;
z-index: 90;
}
```

EDIT:

Here is a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8A9tq/

Sorry, forgot to add it.

EDIT:

Responsive is important.  So I needs to be centered regardless of screen size.

Comment: Could we have a Jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following:

```
#header-home-nav {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then, give the child (#menu) some kind of max-width and auto margins:

```
#menu {
    background: #1B1B1B;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 300px;

    position: relative;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 35px;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I had to increase my max-width to get it to work for me and when I use a super small screen it wraps/floats the buttons below the others. Great work. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Nav centered: http://jsfiddle.net/8A9tq/1/

To center an element you need three things: a set (non-percentage) width, block display (automatic with block level elements, but it's a good practice anyway), and your left and right margins to be set to auto:

```
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
```

So for your example, depending on which element you want to center you could try:

```
  #menu ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 300px;
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #666666;
  }
```

or

```
  #menu {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;   
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 35px; 
  width:300px;
  display:block;
  }
```

and so on

Comment: I removed my other comments. Even with an increase in #menu width on a smaller screen this pushes a button of the screen (unless you scroll).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/4Eqad/

```
#menu {
position: relative;
font-size: 0.8em;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;   
overflow: visible;
z-index: 2;
height: 35px; 
width:100%;    
margin-left:25%;
}
```

Note the new edition is the margin-left:25%. You can make that whatever you would like.

Comment: When I use this Expertise is below the other buttons. I'd like them all in a row.

Comment: I set margin-left to 38% then tested it on a 480 x 640 (small tablet) screen and it puts Expertise off the screen.

Answer (score -1):

Here you can keep your markup and just says to the position has to be 50% left and 50% right.

```
#menu {
position: relative;
font-size: 0.8em;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;   
overflow: visible;
z-index: 2;
height: 35px; 
width:100%;
left: 50%;
right: 50%;
```

}

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uPs8J/2/

Comment: What? It doesn't work. It can't work. Because your CSS makes zero sense.

Comment: It does, it constantly calculateds your #menu to the left and right off your screen, check out the fiddle

Comment: Ok, this version of the fiddle **does** move it, but it isn't centered.

Comment: When I use this jsfiddle on my site it puts it off to the right.